# How to simulate a phone frame playing videos on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I want to show videos on my website, but I want those video to be inside a phone frame, for eg

[image]

I want the video to be playing inside something like that white phone frame.

Hope I was clear enough.  But I have no ideas, on how to actually do this.
Thanks

Comment: Use phone frame image in **background** or in **pseudo** `:before`, `:after`

Answer (score 9):

Hope this helps someone:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="smartphone">
  <div class="content">
    <iframe src="https://wpcoder.co.uk/links/mixkit-man-holding-neon-light-1238-large.mp4" style="width:100%;border:none;height:100%" />
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* The device with borders */
.smartphone {
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;
  height: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 16px black solid;
  border-top-width: 60px;
  border-bottom-width: 60px;
  border-radius: 36px;
}

/* The horizontal line on the top of the device */
.smartphone:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* The circle on the bottom of the device */
.smartphone:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -65px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* The screen (or content) of the device */
.smartphone .content {
  width: 360px;
  height: 640px;
  background: white;
}
```

Live example:
https://codepen.io/neilbannet/pen/WNvqNLR

Answer (score 5):

## Hosting the Video

You have two options:

1. Host the video yourself on your server and embed it in the webpage using `video` and `source` tags. `HTML`:

```html
<video>
   <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <!-- src and type are an example -->
</video>
```

2. (Most popular option) Host the video on a third-party service, such as [YouTube](https://youtube.com/), [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/), or [Dailymotion](https://dailymotion.com/). Then all you need to do is embed the video, an option usually found in the share menu.

## Placing Video on Phone Image

Once you have embedded the video onto your webpage, embed an image of a phone onto the webpage. You might have your image of a phone you want to use, or you could import one from one of the three largest copyright-free image sites:

1. [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/)
2. [Pexels](https://pexels.com/)
3. [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/)

Once you have embedded both video and image onto your webpage, then start editing the HTML and CSS:

1. Give the video a higher `z-index` than the image, so that it appears above it. `CSS`:

```css
/* For Video: */

/* Use this if you hosted the video yourself: */

video {
    z-index: 999; /* any value greater than img's */
}

/* Use this if you used a host: */
iframe {
    z-index: 999; /* any value greater than img's */
}

/* For Image: */

img {
    z-index: -999; /* any value smaller than video's */
}
```

2. Set the video's `position` to `absolute` in the CSS so that it doesn't appear alongside the image, and add pixels on the `left`, `right`, `top`, and/or `bottom` so that it is positioned exactly on the image of the phone. `CSS`:

```css
/* Use this if you hosted yourself: */

video {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px; /* example */
    left: 5px; /* example */
}

/* Use this if you use a host: */

iframe {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px; /* example */
    left: 5px; /* example */
}
```

3. Now adjust the video's `height` and `width` until it fits perfectly into the phone screen. `HTML`:

```html
<!-- Use this if you hosted the video yourself: -->

<video>
   <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="100px" height="500px" />
   <!-- src, type, width and height are an example -->
</video>

<!-- If you used a host, edit width and height in embed tag(s) they provided: -->

<iframe width="100px" height="500px"></iframe>
<!-- Width and height are an example -->
```

I have managed to achieve this by placing a music video from YouTube onto an image of a phone from Unsplash: [JSBin](https://output.jsbin.com/favewiceva/)
Or run code snippet from here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Video in Phone</title>
  <style>

    iframe {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 9999;
      left: 115px;
      top: 133px;
    }

    img {
      z-index: -9999;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505156868547-9b49f4df4e04?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;w=1000&amp;q=80" height="500px" />
<iframe width="140px" height="250px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uYg4cUyJ7v0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you upload it to Youtube, why not directly put the video in a <video> tag, not in the <iframe> tag? Are there any benefits to it?

Comment: FYI: There's an error in your instructions. You state, "2. Set the video's position to absolute in the CSS ..." and then in the code that follows you've got `position: relative`.